# Devanagari and Latin fonts in the same file with Lualatex in Spacemacs

Tags: luatex, emacs, devanagari

I switched my Texteditor from TexMaker to Spacemacs, but am not anymore able to compile my Sanskrit Translations with mixed Language into a pdf with LuaLatex. In TexMaker it was possible. In Spacemacs I do not find the clue.

Here is a short version of my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{ngerman}
    \setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
    \newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\begin{document}
\begin{sanskrit}
परमहंस
\end{sanskrit}
paramahaṃsa
\end{document}
```

In the manual of Spacemacs `https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/latex/README.html` I see that as a TeX-Engine you can use xetex and luatex. I tried both in adding to the end of the .tex-document:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-engine: xetex   ///or luatex
%%% End:
```

Did not work.

I also tried this:

```
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
              '((latex :variables latex-build-engine 'xetex   /// or 'luatex)))
```

Any clue how I can create with spacemacs that file?

Comment: Don’t use `babel` and `poylglossia` at the same time. Both packages support German and Sanskrit (I’d rather use `babel`, but I’m biased).

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

In the end of the file:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```